# What is the expected metadata for my entity class for serializer to work?

Tags: symfony, jmsserializerbundle

I am trying to configure JMS/Serializer to exclude properties of my entities.

Yet I am stuck at following exception:

```
Expected metadata for class My\FooBundle\Entity\Asset to be defined in ~/src/test/src/My/FooBundle/Resources/config/serializer/Entity.Asset.yml.
```

What is the expected metadata I need to define there?

My `Entity.serializer.yml` consists only of

```
Asset:
    exclusion_policy: ALL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Reading the doc does help](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/yml_reference): The key for the entity in the yaml file must be the fully qualified class name, hence:

```
My\FooBundle\Entity\Asset:
    exclusion_policy: ALL
```

works as expected.